# Включить query_id в pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста по какой причине query_id в pg_stat_activity не считается.
Поправил postgresql.conf таким образом:

- compute_query_id = on
- shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
- log_duration = on
- log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] query_id=%Q'

Версия:
PostgreSQL 15.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit